# Is this closure in global scope?

Tags: javascript, closures

That is closure:

```
function xPlusPlus() {
   var x = 0;
   return function () {
     console.log(x++);
   }
}

var inner = xPlusPlus();
inner();// 0
inner();// 1
inner();// 2
```

But, is that closure too?

```
var x = 0;

function xPlusPlus() {
  console.log(x++);
}
xPlusPlus();// 0
xPlusPlus();// 1
xPlusPlus();// 2
```

I will be very grateful for the answer

Comment: YES!! It doesn't matter what scope is causing that behavior.

Comment: Think of the term "closure" as "live snapshot of all outer scopes". This includes the global scope. Also, functions aren't closures, they *create* them.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thank you!

Comment: @Tomalak  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there nothing else wrapping your snippets `xPlusPlus` function declaration is in global scope, which means it creates closures attached to global scope.

The difference is that in

- first case `x` is in `xPlusPlus` scope
- second case `x` is in global

This is **first case** execution conversation:

```
function xPlusPlus() {
   var x = 0;
   return function () {
     console.log(x++);
   }
}

var inner = xPlusPlus();
inner();
```

**Line `console.log(x++);`**: 'Hey anonymous function, do you know variable `x`?'

**anonymous function**: 'NO, go one level up!'

**Line `console.log(x++);`**: 'Hey `xPlusPlus` function, do you know variable `x`?'

**`xPlusPlus` function**: 'YES I have it for you!'

**Line `console.log(x++);`**: 'Cool! Let me increment `x` by one'

**THE END**

---

This is **second case** execution conversation:

```
var x = 0;

function xPlusPlus() {
  console.log(x++);
}
xPlusPlus();
```

**Line `console.log(x++);`**: 'Hey function `xPlusPlus`, do you know variable `x`?'

**function `xPlusPlus`**: 'NO, go one level up, you'll drive into global scope!'

**Line `console.log(x++);`**: 'Hey `global scope` function, do you know variable `x`?'

**`global scope`**: 'YES I have it for you!'

**Line `console.log(x++);`**: 'Cool! Let me increment `x` by one'

**THE END**

Comment: Большое спасибо, Олег! :)

Comment: :) vsegda pozhaluysta